# GKE Node Pool Upgrade Stuck initially due to quota; Unable to rollback, cancel or retry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

On 8/6 I recreated a private / regional GKE cluster to enable confidential VMs.  The node pool upgrade got stuck as the project resource quota for n2d machine types was hit.  To remedy this I requested the quota be raised, which it was, and I scaled down the number of machines in other pools so that our quota is in the green.  The node pool upgrade never finished and still displays the warning about the quota limit.

I can not perform any operations on the cluster or the node pool due to the state that it is in.  I've tried rolling back with `gcloud container node-pools rollback` and `gcloud container operations cancel` with no luck.  The former says I must wait for the operation to finish.  The latter says the operation can't be canceled because it is complete.  The status of the operation when I use `gcloud container operations describe` is

> 'OPERATION_ABORTED: operation was aborted'

I feel I've exhausted my options and don't know what to do next.  Has anyone run into this before?

Edit: Adding output of `gcloud container node-pools describe`.

```
autoscaling:
  enabled: true
  maxNodeCount: 20
  minNodeCount: 1
conditions:
- canonicalCode: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED
  message: "Insufficient quota to satisfy the request: waiting on IG: instance <instance self_link> is still CREATING. Last attempt error: [QUOTA_EXCEEDED] Instance '<instance name>'\
    \ creation failed: Quota 'N2D_CPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 48.0 in region <region>.\
    \ - ."
- canonicalCode: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED
  message: "Insufficient quota to satisfy the request: waiting on IG: instance <instance self_link>
    \ is still CREATING. Last attempt error: [QUOTA_EXCEEDED] Instance '<instance name>'\
    \ creation failed: Quota 'N2D_CPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 48.0 in region <region>.\
    \ - ."
config:
  diskSizeGb: 30
  diskType: pd-standard
  imageType: COS
  machineType: n2d-standard-4
  metadata:
    disable-legacy-endpoints: 'true'
  oauthScopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
  serviceAccount: <GKE service account>
  shieldedInstanceConfig:
    enableIntegrityMonitoring: true
  tags:
  - private-persistence
initialNodeCount: 1
instanceGroupUrls:
- <zonal IG 1 self_link>
- <zonal IG 2 self_link
- <zonal IG 3 self_link>
locations:
- <zone 1>
- <zone 2>
- <zone 3>
management:
  autoRepair: true
  autoUpgrade: true
maxPodsConstraint:
  maxPodsPerNode: '110'
name: <node-pool name>
networkConfig:
  podIpv4CidrBlock: 10.5.0.0/20
  podRange: pod-range
podIpv4CidrSize: 24
selfLink: <node pool self_link>
status: RUNNING_WITH_ERROR
statusMessage: "us-central1-f: Insufficient quota to satisfy the request: waiting\
  \ on IG: instance <instance self_link>\
  \ is still CREATING. Last attempt error: [QUOTA_EXCEEDED] Instance '<instance name>\
  \ creation failed: Quota 'N2D_CPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 48.0 in region <region>.\
  \ - ."
upgradeSettings:
  maxSurge: 1
version: 1.18.17-gke.1901
```

Comment: What's the output of `gcloud container node-pools describe ...`?

Comment: I've updated the post with the output of `node-pools describe` @GariSingh

Comment: It looks like quota still is the issue. Are you sure it has been raised ? I think you can simply try to repeat the upgrade operation once new quota is applied. It seems to me it didn't get stuck in fact. The error messages you get make perfect sense. As this operation was aborted, as one message says, you cannot of course cancel it as it has already been canceled. And you cannot rollback it either as the change has not been applied so there is nothing to be rolled back from yet. Does this node pool remain unusable at the moment ?

Comment: @mario I am certain.  The quota shows that usage is 34/48.  The node pool and cluster both remain unusable.

Comment: Please file an issue at [Google's issue tracker][(https://issuetracker.google.com). It's possible it is a bug in GCP.